# Importing Tkinter using PyCharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

Currently working on Python (version 3.7.8) programming, using PyCharm software.

1. I would like to install tkinter for future python projects with future and pip plugins.
2. I tried to follow a series of tutorials, but all I get is error messages, such as tracebacks.
3. Source code as follows:

```
import tkinter
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are many ways to configure a python interpreter in pycharm. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html. On the left side of the page you can see all of the options.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please always include any error messages you get. ([Edit] your question.) See [ask]. That said, most people use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to install the dependencies per project, so that different projects can use different versions of a dependency, and it's easy to install dependencies automatically.